# Why does it take 24 hours for tendons to give feedback on whether the loads they received were excessive?

Tags: human-biology, pain, tendons

I heard in this interview of Jill Cook (tendon researcher) on https://youtu.be/GKkSp-TlofI?t=230:

> Tendons talk to you 24 hours later. So what happens if if I put load on a tendon today, it will tell me tomorrow it's been happy with the load.

Why does it take 24 hours for tendons to give feedback on whether the loads they received were excessive?

Comment: In this [article](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.berh.2006.12.003), they say that they believe any pain that *lasts more than 24h during rehabilitation should be considered a contraindication*. No reference was cited for this reasoning. I believe it takes 24h for recovery. My suggestion is that you write to the author herself asking for the relevant reference. You can then post that as an answer. It is unlikely that you would receive an answer here because this is a very specialized topic.

Comment: It sounds like the person in the interview was referring to delayed onset muscle soreness, of which there is an interesting wikipedia article